# Compound alt-key mappings work in Vim but not NeoVim

Tags: neovim, linux

I have a number of alt key re-mappings in my Vim .vimrc that I copied over to my Neovim init.vim file.  The single alt key mappings work fine but any compound re-mappings are not working.  It seems like NeoVim is ignoring the Alt on the second keystroke.

For example:

```
" This works in both Vim and NeoVim
map <esc>x :qall<CR>

" This works in Vim but NeoVim will start the keystroke recorder
map <esc>q<esc>q :qall!<CR>
```

Is there any way to make this work?  I'm using terminator under Linux if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! I'm a bit confused. I see in your mapping `<esc>x` where your text is mentioning the alt key. In such case I would expect a `<M-x>` mapping. Could you share the OS you are using together with the exact key combination you try to map?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20. I want to use the Alt key which in Terminator seems to generate things like `^[x` for `Atl-x`.  This works fine in Vim and for single keypresses in NeoVim.

Comment: I can reproduce the `<esc>x` behavior on Ubuntu WSL. But unfortunately on my machine the `<esc>q<esc>q` mapping is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
map <M-x> :qall<CR>
map <M-q><M-q> :qall!<CR>
```

Remarks:

- For command mapping it is recommended to use the `<Cmd>` modifier
- Unless good reasons the `noremap` is recommended over `map`

```
noremap <M-x> <Cmd>qall<CR>
noremap <M-q><M-q> <Cmd>qall!<CR>
```

Comment: And unless you have good reason to want them in multiple modes, nnoremap (two ns)

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot.